# Form::checkbox on Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I just started learning laravel and I have the following situation:

I have a table which is called 'cities' and a table 'users'. To connect them I have a table users_cities.

I am trying to do a form using laravel

```
@extends('welcome')

@section('content')

    <h1>Cities</h1>

    @foreach ($cities as $city)

    {!! Form::checkbox($city->name, $city->id, null, ['class' => 'field']) !!}{!! $city->name !!}

    @endforeach

    @foreach ($citiesSelect as $citySelect)

    {!! $citySelect->id !!}

    @endforeach 

@stop
```

And it`s bringing the name of the cities on the first foreach, and on the second is bringing the ids of the cities that should be checked.

Basically is bringing the entries on the database which has the id_user selected.

But I can't figure out how to bring the checkboxes on the first foreach selected using the result of the second foreach.

Comment: try passing 3rd argument as true instead of null

Comment: yes, thats what i want but dinamically with the result of the second foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create array of city ids like this

```
$selectedCitiesIds = array_map(function($city) {
  return $city->id;
}, $citiesSelect);
```

then

```
{!! Form::checkbox($city->name, $city->id, (in_array($city->id, $selectedCitiesIds)), ['class' => 'field']) !!}{!! $city->name !!}
```

Comment: I don`t have a citiesSelect, that comes from my controller = \App\Cities::all() and then it says my second arg should be an array..

Comment: I got to do the array as $selectedCitiesIds[] = $city->id; and it worked. cheers

Answer (score 0):

simply add a 'true' argument to your statement like such:

```
Form::checkbox($city->name, $city->id, true, ['class' => 'field'])
```

Comment: I think I wasn't very clear. I want to use the result of the second foreach to set it true or not

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too.

In this case you have an array called **cmbbolsas** and in the checkbox input you can use it

```
@foreach ($cmbbolsas as $key=>$value)
   <input type="checkbox" name="bolsas" value={{$key}}> {{$value}}</br>
@endforeach
```

I hope it works for you :3